# Problemas com Json e local storage

Tags: javascript, html, json

Estou aprendendo a usar o javascript, estou seguindo um tutorial,ja revisei o codigo, parece identico, mas simplesmente não salva.
Apos eu atualizar a pagina oque eu exclui ou adicionei não mantem, volta para o padrão.

O codigo:

```
//referenciando os elementos
var listElement = document.querySelector('#app ul');
var inputElement = document.querySelector('#app input');
var buttonElement = document.querySelector('#app button');

//armazenamento de ToDo no JS
var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list_todos')) || [] ;

//To do padrão
var todos = [
    'Fazer cafe',
    'Estudar Java',
    'Estudar JavaScript'
];

//função para renderizar toDO
function renderTodos(){
    listElement.innerHTML = ''; //removendo o conteudo do listelement
    //for para arrays
    for (todo of todos){
        //criando os elementos
        var todoElement = document.createElement('li');
        var todoText = document.createTextNode(todo);
        todoElement.appendChild(todoText);
        listElement.appendChild(todoElement);

        //excluindo elementos
        var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
        var linkText = document.createTextNode('Excluir');
        linkElement.appendChild(linkText);
        todoElement.appendChild(linkElement);
        linkElement.setAttribute('href', '#'); //href do 'a'

        //identificar qual remover(pos)
        var pos = todos.indexOf(todo);
        linkElement.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteTodo(' + pos + ')');

    }
}

renderTodos();

//função adicionar to do
function addTodo(){
    var todoText = inputElement.value; //valor do input

    todos.push(todoText);//adicionar no aray
    inputElement.value = ''; //apaga o atual 
    renderTodos(); //renderizar novamente 
    saveToStorage();

}
//botao para adicionar o todo
buttonElement.onclick = addTodo;

//função para excluir
function deleteTodo(pos){
    todos.splice(pos, 1); //remove uma quantidade de item
    renderTodos();
    saveToStorage();
}
//função de salvamento
function saveToStorage(){
    localStorage.setItem('list_todos', JSON.stringify (todos));
}
```

O HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <ul> </ul>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Digite um todo" />
    <button>Adicionar</button>
    </div>

    <script src="JSAPP.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

O console:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foto do storage:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(parece que esta a funcionar, porem na tela exibe o contrario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema que eu estou vendo no seu script está aqui:

```
//armazenamento de ToDo no JS
var todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list_todos')) || [] ;

//To do padrão
var todos = [
    'Fazer cafe',
    'Estudar Java',
    'Estudar JavaScript'
];
```

Repare que ao abrir a página, você verifica se tem alguma informação na chave `list_todos` do seu `localStorage`. Se tiver, você faz o parse e armazena em `todos`, se não tiver, você inicializa o `todos` com um array vazio.

Porém logo em seguida você sobrescreve qualquer que seja o array armazenado em `todos` com esse novo array `['Fazer cafe', 'Estudar Java', 'Estudar JavaScript']`.

Imagino que a ideia seria inicializar o `todos` com esse array apenas se não existisse nada no `localStorage`, então seu código deveria ser algo do tipo

```
//armazenamento de ToDo no JS
var todos = 
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('list_todos')) || 
    ['Fazer cafe', 'Estudar Java', 'Estudar JavaScript'];
```

Comment: Funcionou amigo,muito obrigado. Interessante que eu revi o tutorial para ter certeza e sim,estava igual (o da rocketseat), n sei o pq disso, mas muito obrigado por solucionar meu problema.